# Can I serve a website on any port I want to?

Tags: port, webserver

I am building a web-server. Can I send web documents through any port I like, or are there limitations?

If so, what are they?

Comment: Yes, you can. It's done quite often, actually. The limitation is that you can't use a port that's used (or reserved) by another service. Can you explain more about your situation and why you'd want to do this to make this a more practical question?

Comment: in general, yes. On linux, its a good idea to use a port over 1024 if you're non root (else you may need to start the program as root, and drop its privileges after that, or run it on another port and forward it through the OS firewall) - I'm not aware of any such issues on windows.

Comment: @slhck theres no specific reason, other than i am building a mini webserver, and in choosing a port am wondering if I should use a specified one, or an arbitrary one, or a unique one just to be different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically: Yes, you can server webpages on any port from port number 0 to port number 65535. (2<sup>16</sup> port numbers).

However:

1. Make sure the port is not already in use.
2. Try to avoid other [well known port numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) to avoid needless confusion.
3. Ports below 1024 are considered privileged.
4. Port 80 is the default port for HTTP. If you use a non standard port (and no port forwarding in your border) then you will need to tell your browser which port to use to fetch webpages. E.g. by using `http://yourwebsitename.tld:1234` (where 1234 is a port number).

Comment: 8080 is a pretty common 'alt' website port that might be worth considering.

Comment: It is, probably because it is easy to remember. Much the same as the alternative 2222 for ssh (normally on port 22).

Comment: Bear in mind that a number of companies block access to non-standard ports numbers - so people who work there won't be able to access your web server.