# How to choose open port number?

Tags: port-forwarding, webserver, easyphp

I installed easyPHP and opened a port on my firewall so that other people can access to my webserver. The default port is 8888. But I am wondering how do you choose a port number? Is it really ambiguous or there is a "prefered" range of port number?

Comment: @JakeGould Thanks for your comment it really helped me.!

Comment: Possibly related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476987/best-tcp-port-number-range-for-internal-applications

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I serve a website on any port I want to?](https://superuser.com/questions/538597/can-i-serve-a-website-on-any-port-i-want-to)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A port number is a 16-bit unsigned integer, thus ranging from 0 to 65535 (although 0 cannot be used for TCP; it has a special meaning for UDP).

You can use pretty much any port number in the range, however there are some guiding rules:

1. (On Unix based systems at least), only root can bind to ports below 1024.
2. You ideally don't want a port typically associated with another common service as this can cause problems with some firewalls.
3. Expanding on (2) above - On Linux systems at least, there is a file `/etc/services` which has a list of common services - you can use this for guidance.

The "ideal" port to run an HTTP service is port 80, and the ideal port for HTTPS is 443, because those ports are associated with their respective services.  If this is not practical (and it often isn't - some routers are too stupid to handle a web interface and port forward externally on the same port), it's common to pick a "themed" port - port 8080 is pretty common, as is port 8000.

Comment: On modern Windows versions you have to have administrator privileges in order to bind to ports below 1024 as well.

Comment: @enkryptor: Which versions are those? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @grawity I believe it's Windows 7 and later. You can also give a permission to a non-admin user for a specific url via `netsh http add urlacl`

Comment: @enkryptor I have nginx running on port 80, non-localhost ip, and I'm not admin in this system.

Comment: @Braiam good for you

Comment: @enkryptor: That command only applies when port 80 is in use by http.sys (IIS et al.); it works in terms of reserving HTTP paths, not TCP ports.

Comment: @grawity correct, it's for http only, that's why it starts with "netsh http"

Comment: The Windows "services" file, funnily enough, lives at `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\services`. There's probably some interesting WinSock & BSD heritage there. But the most authoritative source is the [IANA Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml).

Comment: @Bob Microsoft's original TCP/IP stack was a more or less direct port of early 1990s BSD sockets.